# Repairing bumper scratch

Tags: paint, body-work, paint-scratches, bumper

I have scratches on both sides of my bumper. They are invisible while standing. Thus, they don't need to be perfect. Can I fix it myself?

[image: bumper]

[image: bumper]

Comment: Btw, it's a Tesla Model 3

Comment: Is that definitely scratched down to the plastic, it is not just something that has smeared over the paint?

Comment: Agree with @HandyHowie ... this looks like something a Magic Eraser would take care of if not some rubbing with your fingers.

Comment: If they do need touching up, and are normally not seen, or course you can do it yourself. Make sure you prepare it properly and mask off anything nearby that you might get unwanted paint on accidentally.

Comment: ... and if you are unsure of your skill, practice on something else first, like on a bit of junk in the shed.

Comment: @HandyHowie correct, it goes down to the plastic. Do I need some kind of paint?

Comment: If you have no experience of spraying, seeing as it is in a place that isn’t really visible, I would be tempted to use an artists paintbrush and carefully paint directly over the scratches.